# Spark File Format Escaping \n Loading CSV

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a CSV pipe delimited data file using spark. It's quote qualified. A block of text has a /n in it and it's causing the read to corrupt. What I don't understand is that it's quote qualified text so surely it should just skip that!? The rows themselves are CR+LN delimited.

Anyhow it's not. How do I get around this? I can cleanse them out on extract but doesn't seem that elegant to me.

This is what I'm using to load the data

```
val sch = spark.table("db.mytable").schema
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(sch)
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("quote", "\"")
  .load("/yadaydayda/mydata.txt")
```

Comment: There's no consensus in CSV format; even though there's an RFC, many parsers don't fully support it, and the ones who do go beyond it anyway _(e.g. I think custom escape chars for embedded quotes are not in the RFC)_. Among these robust parsers, some are Open Source... but not necessarily with a license that allows Apache projects to use them. Duh.

Comment: Bottom line: implement your own parser utility with `uniVocity` Java lib, then pipeline the records into a DataFrame. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to know I'm not the only one who's dealt with this issue in Spark!

Spark reads files line-by-line, so CSVs with newlines in them cause problems for the parser. Reading line-by-line makes it easier for Spark to handle large CSV files, rather than trying to parse all of the content for quotes, which would significantly impair performance for a case is more likely to not be an issue when trying to have high-performing analytics.

For cases where I knew newlines were a possibility, I've used a third party CSV parsing library, run the CSV "lines" through that (which would handle the newlines correctly), strip the newlines, write/cache the file somewhere, and read from that cached file. For a production use case, those files would be loaded into a database, or for log files or something where you don't want them in a database, using Parquet like you suggested works pretty well, or really just enforcing the lack of newlines somewhere before the files get to Spark.

Comment: Yeah after to some consideration escaping record delimiters is really hard for any platform. I think the approach is to think more holistically about the data engineering problem to avoid txt parsing if at all possible (e.g. using features in data provisioning tools like data factory to convert to typed formats) or to cleanse them out upstream before the preparation stage

Answer (score 0):

Got around this by initially striping them on extract. The final solution I settled on however was to use a parquet format on extract then all these problems just go away.